# Is there a way to create identical mesh on opposite surfaces?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am using a plugin to apply boundary conditions to the model, that will work only of the meshes on the opposite side are similar. My model is multiple cylinders inside the cube and touches the surface of the cube.

1. Created the surface boundary mesh on three faces by clicking the surface
2. Created the shell layer mesh from that
3. Then copied the mesh to the other faces.

But I need to create multiple models like this. I tried to create a Python script from the journal file to do this. But it is only working for the file (dimensions) from which the script was created. Not helpful for other models, resulted in the following error

error in
 mask = ('[#0:11 #ffc00000 #ffffffff:13 #ff]', ), )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be default, `mask` related commands are used while journaling the python commands in replay, journal and other files. These are Abaqus internal syntax and hence are superfast.
However, these masking is specific to the same model, hence cannot be used whenever there is slight change in the geometry.

To avoid these commands, when you open Abaqus, first run following commands in Command Line Interface then do operations. Now the journal and other files, they will not have masking related command.

```
session.journalOptions.setValues(replayGeometry=INDEX, recoverGeometry=INDEX)
```